# Is Lisp a virtual machine like JVM?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why would someone refer to Lisp as a virtual machine like JVM?

Comment: Do you have a source to that reference? The person might be referring to Clojure, a LISP dialect _for_ the JVM.

Comment: because they wanted to emphasize Common Lisp's RTS - run time system - aspect over the "Common Lisp the language" aspect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably because that person refers to a specific implementation of Lisp which runs on top of a Virtual Machine? Various Lisp systems since atleast the 70s have been running on top of specialized virtual machines. Some current implementations like CLISP and CMUCL still have their own virtual machines.

Virtual machines for Lisp are usually specially tailored for the demands of Lisp. They provide the necessary primitive data types (like cons cells, symbols and large integers), instruction set (generic function calling, run-time data type checking, ...), memory management (garbage collection) and other services (dynamic loading of code). They often provide some kind of extended stack machine.

Comment: I don't know that I'd call CMU CL "running on a VM". But it's been a long good while since I looked under the hood.

Comment: @Vatine: CMUCL has a compiler to 'byte code' and an execution engine for that: http://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/compiler-hint.html#toc189

Comment: Heh, learn something new every day. I've always solidly placed CMU CL (and SBCL) in the 'compiles to native' camp. Nice to see that it has that as an option as well.